# Update salesforce objects with OLEDB connection in SSIS (DBAmp)

Tags: c#, .net, ssis, salesforce, dbamp

I'm using SSIS OLEDB connection to view data from Salesforce. Connection driver for OLEDB is [DBAmp from forceamp.com](http://forceamp.com)

My question here is there a way to update records on Salesforce object directly from SSIS. I tried on both [OleDbCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DbCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) to perform this update, nothing works.

Here is my sample.

```
ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections["SF"];
OleDbConnection conn = null;
if (cm.CreationName == "OLEDB")
{
     Wrap.IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100 cmParams = cm.InnerObject as Wrap.IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100;
     conn = cmParams.GetConnectionForSchema() as OleDbConnection;
}
else            
     conn = cm.AcquireConnection(null) as OleDbConnection;            

if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)            
     conn.Open();            

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Update ffpx_trgoinv__SwissPostStatus__c set Name = 'Change' where Id = 'a4p0E0000005Kj0QAE'", conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I know this is possible via SQL Linked server but I wanted to use it in C# within SSIS without creating a linked server.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I don't get the error at all. cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() runs without any error but the update is not happening.